# How does stealth work in Far Cry?

Tags: far-cry

I recently picked up `Far Cry Classic` on the Xbox 360.  After playing through a few levels I became frustrated with guards always spotting me.  This included such things as seeing me in a dense jungle or through a large rock.  It seemed to only require that a guard was facing my direction in order to see me, regardless of obstacles between us.

Additionally, the red/orange/yellow/green indicators also seem to be somewhat frustrating.  For example, if I fire a sniper rifle from a few hundred metres and then quickly move to a new location the guards seem to stick to a certain indicator.  Nearby guards will rush to the location I fired the gun, and remain in that position with a mix of yellow and orange indicators.  I sat nearby for over ten minutes but the guards never moved or changed colour.

In other scenarios, if I turn a guard orange by being almost spotted I can quickly escape so that he turns back to yellow and then green.

I enjoyed the original release on the PC over ten years ago, and remember playing through some levels by using stealth.  I downloaded the first game on Steam but it seems to have the same problems as the console versions (this version is titled `Far Cry` rather than `Far Cry Classic`, and still has the older graphics).

So how does stealth actually work in the newer versions of the game?  Any insight to allow me to play through some levels using stealth (i.e. either sneaking through outposts/camps/patrols or picking off guards)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the latest patch for Far Cry may have introduced texture bugs that allows NPCs to [see through walls](https://steamcommunity.com/app/13520/discussions/0/619573787433651412/).

For the PC, there seems to be two solutions:

> However, if you (like me) don't appreciate the added challenge this
>   bug brings, you are able to fix it in one of two ways:
>
> - If you want to keep it vanilla, install the "un-official" 1.41 patch from here: http://farcry.filefront.com/file/Unofficial_Patch_141;78338
> - If you want some additional bug fixes, install the fan mod "FCAM" from here: http://www.moddb.com/mods/farcry-addon-mod-fcam
>
> I installed FCAM myself and it seems to fix it. To install it you will
>   need to create a "Mods" folder in your /Steam/SteamApps/common/FarCry
>   folder and extract the files there. Then you can use the icon on the
>   desktop, or start up the game from Steam, go to "Mods" on the menu
>   screen, and activate it there.

Comment: I suspect this problem also made it into the console editions somehow.

Answer (score 0):

To disable the enemies being able to see through some materials such as canvas, you can "downgrade" the game to the version 1.32 by installing the 64-bit patch (you must be running a 64-bit operating system) as 1.4 was never supported for this architecture. This "feature" added in the 1.4 update is generally considered as a bug.
Install [64-bit patch](https://www.fileplanet.com/153236/150000/fileinfo/Far-Cry-AMD64-/-WinXP-Pro-x64-Upgrade-%5BEnglish%5D) first, optionally **followed by** [Exclusive/Enhanced Content update](https://www.fileplanet.com/153242/150000/fileinfo/Far-Cry-AMD64-/-WinXP-Pro-x64-Exclusive-Content). The [GOG version](https://www.gog.com/game/far_cry) or installing from retail disc (potentially uses unsupported DRM) may be recommended as Steam can overwrite changed files.

from `Readme - Enhanced Content Update.txt`:

> 1. Install the original 32 bit version of FarCry
> 2. Install the AMD64 Update Patch
> 3. Install the AMD64 Enhanced Content Patch

-

> AMD64 Enhanced Content Update
>
> AMD 64 Update additions
>
> - Optimised and refactored code to take advantage of 64 bit architecture.
> - Two AMD64 exclusive multiplayer maps – MP_Stronghold and MP_Gorge
> - Added Offset bump mapping support.
> - Added higher resolution textures and objects.
> - Increased some viewing distances
> - Updated the Pier level with new content

You can verify the game version in the main menu.

Comment: PC Gaming Wiki backups for the files: https://community.pcgamingwiki.com/files/file/442-far-cry-amd64-64-bit-upgrade-patch/ https://community.pcgamingwiki.com/files/file/443-far-cry-amd64-64-bit-enhanced-content-patch/